# Infinite scroll does not work with ion-content fullscreen

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ion-infinite-scroll, ion-content

I am using infinite scroll in Ionic-3 and I hide Main-Header and showing Mini-header  on scroll.It is a causing problem in android only and problem is :
On scrolling Main-Header Stuck behind as shown in Image,

I used ion-content with **fullscreen** to hide and show header. but when I use **fullscreen** property in 'ion-content' it resolve header issue but after using **fullscreen** infinite-scroll 
does not work in Android

[image]

Here is my test code.

```
<!--Main-Header-->
<ion-header [hidden]="isScrollStarted">
</ion-header>

<!--Mini-Header-->
<ion-header [hidden]="!isScrollStarted">
</ion-header>

<ion-content fullscreen>

<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
<ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `class="ion-no-padding"` in `<ion-content>` tag.like this:

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true" class="ion-no-padding">
</ion-content>
```